# How to clone the objects scale to a definded plane

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want to clone objects scale to a plane using javascript

I tried using this but this doesn't seem to work

```
this.plane.setAttribute('animation__scale', {
      property: 'scale',
      dur: 300,
      from: '0.001 0.001 0.001',
      to: this.el.object3D.scale.clone(),
});
```

but it does transform to defined scale for instance,

```
this.plane.setAttribute('animation__scale', {
      property: 'scale',
      dur: 300,
      from: '0.001 0.001 0.001',
      to: '1 1 1',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The to: value must be a string.
The object3D.scale is of type THREE.Vector3.
You can write a function that converts the vector to a string.

```
function vectorToString(vec){
    if (vec){
        return vec.x.toString()+" "+vec.y.toString()+" "+vec.z.toString();
    } else {
        console.log('vectorToString error. vec:', vec);
        return null;
    }
}
```

then you can get the scale, convert it to a string, and use it in the animation params.

```
   let newScale = vectorToString( this.el.object3D.scale.clone() );
    this.plane.setAttribute('animation__scale', {
          property: 'scale',
          dur: 300,
          from: '0.001 0.001 0.001',
          to: newScale
    });
```